# Force copy bundle resource of a file in Xcode's new build system

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, fastlane, build-script

I'm using the Xcode new build system and within the build system, I have a script that creates a `file.plist` with it as the explicit output and another script that takes in `file.plist` as input and modifies the `file.plist`. Then I put `file.plist` into the `Copy Bundle Resources` Phase.

This way works generally for clean builds and in Xcode builds. But it doesn't work in fastlane because the script to modify `file.plist` runs but the changes do not get copied over into the build directory. Making it run in fastlane requires a clean to occur before building.

Does anyone have experience with this issue and how did you go about solving this problem?

Comment: Move the script earlier in the build process?

Comment: The build scripts happens before `Copy Bundle Resources`

Comment: OK so this must be a fastlane thing. Added that to the tags.